# Как получить идентификатор имея частную ссылку на канал телеграмм, используя python3?

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

Как получить идентификатор канала телеграмм (выглядит он так -1001750197994) имея ссылку: (один из вариантов как может выглядить tg://join?invite=+mTSqtJfEnxk3MWUy , может и так, сути не меняет t.me/+mTSqtJfEnxk3MWUy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Специальный бот есть. @GetIdTeleBot Отправляете ему ссылку он в ответ пришлет ID. Можно написать скрипт который будет слать боту ссылку и обратно получать id